# Can I expand a macro argument once without using a scratch register?

Tags: tex-core, expansion

I'm still trying to get my head around how expansion works in TeX. One thing I can't figure out is how to expand a macro argument once without having to use a scratch register as an intermediate.

As an example, consider the following code, which defines an alternative to `\meaning` with a few bells and whistles:

```
\long\def\printmeaning#1%
{%
    \def\@tempa{#1}%
    {\tt\expandafter\string\@tempa} is defined as\par
    {\tt\meaning#1}%
}
\printmeaning\centerline

\bye
```

The output (produced with `pdftex`) is

[image]

So far, so good. However, I'm wondering whether I really have to use a scratch register (such as `\@tempa`), here. Is there a way to print the name of the control sequence passed to `\printmeaning` without using a scratch register (or some other temporary macro)?

Comment: `\def\printmeaning #1{{\tt\meaning#1}}` should work. Or you can aslo do `\def\printmeaningwithname #1{{\tt\expandafter\meaning\csname #1\endcsname}}` and then `\printmeaningwithname {centerline}` (advantageous in latex when not wanting to always do `\makeatletter` etc...).

Comment: @jfbu Thanks, but I don't think that answers my question. In my example, I use a scratch register in order to print the name of the control sequence passed as argument to `\printmeaning`. My question is: can I print that control-sequence name without having to use a scratch register? (I'll clarify my question.)

Comment: ah sorry you wanted `\def\printmeaning #1{{\tt\string#1} is defined as:\endgraf {\tt\meaning#1}}` (I think)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can directly use `\string#1` if `#1` is a control sequence:

```
\def\printmeaning #1{{\tt\string#1} is defined as:\endgraf {\tt\meaning#1}}
```

(with perhaps an additional `\endgraf` at the end. Or `\par`. I tend to use `\endgraf` for no reason outside of real typography).

Comment: but `\printmeaning\par` will not work, as the definition was not prefixed with `\long`... `\printmeaning\endgraf` does work :)

Comment: Ah thanks. I don't think I had even tried `\string#1`.

Comment: you should think of `#1` as really exactly as if it was replaced by the macro argument, as if you had typed it in directly.